# How many such squares can be formed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$S$ is a set of all points $(a, b)$ such that $0 ≤ a$, $b ≤ k$. How many squares are there such that all the $4$ vertices are from set $S$?

For diagonal squares, a square must contain odd points on its side.
so that we can join the mid points of each side.
suppose we take $5$ points on each side,
$$5*5 will make = 1^{2}$$
$$3*3 will make = 3^{2}$$ etc

so when $n$ is odd, its summation of all odd squares till $k$.
& for even similar approach.

Can you guide me further? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's [this](http://oeis.org/A002415) sequence. It says, "$a(n) =$ number of squares with corners on an $n\times n$ grid."